# The array cannot hold the same name twice, when a new string is to be added the program should check to see if the name is already there

Tags: c++

How can i write a for loop in c++ to user can' t write the same name twice in an array?

i already write this

```
for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    cout << i+1 <<" : ";
    cin >> name[i];

    if(name[i] == "empty")
    {
        cout << "Empty cannot be used";
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: sounds like you may want [std::set](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/) instead of a plain array

Comment: `for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j) { if (name[i] == name[j]) { cout << "same name twice\n"; return 0; } }`

Comment: @dave using a `set` is only half of the solution, OP wants to populate the array with 5 different names, if you push the same name into a set 5 times it will have only one element

Answer (score 3):

A `std::set` is an appropriate C++ standard library container to model the names. This is because it can't contain duplicates. To that end consider

```
std::set<std::string> names; // has the added bonus that names will be sorted
do {
    std::string name;
    std::cin >> name;
    const bool contains = names.find(name) != names.end(); // Is 'name' already there?
    if (contains){
        // ToDo - issue an error
    } else {
        names.add(name); // No real need for the 'else' branch, as readding is a no-op.
    }    
} while (names.size() != 5);
```

Comment: Your can alternatively replace `find` with `insert` and check its return value: `if (!names.insert(name).second) { /* already exists */ } else { /* added */ }`

Answer (score 0):

You need to prompt the user first, then loop through the array:

```
string names[5];
string name;

cout << "Enter a name: ";
cin >> name;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    if (names[i] == name)
    {
        cout << "That name cannot be used";
        return 0;
    }
}

cout << "That name can be used";
```